# How to set Option of Select HTML tag using data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

How to set Option of Select  HTML tag using data- attribute?

**HTML**

```
<select  class="form-control shade_custom_option valid" id="1">
  <option data-isnone="true" selected="selected" value="1">None</option>
  <option data-isnone="false"  value="2">Text1</option>
  <option data-isnone="false" value="3">Text2</option>
</select>

<select  class="form-control shade_custom_option valid" id="2">
  <option data-isnone="true" selected="selected" value="1">None</option>
  <option data-isnone="false"  value="2">Text1</option>
  <option data-isnone="false" value="3">Text2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(".shade_custom_option").each(function (index, value) {
  // var optionSelected = $("option:selected", value);
  // How to get option with  data-isnone="true"? and set it as selected option.
});
```

Comment: `$(".shade_custom_option option[data-isnone=true]").prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `select` value to the value of the matching `option`:

```
$(".shade_custom_option").each(function (index, value) {
  $(this).val( $(this).find('option[data-isnone=true]').val() );
});
```